# using jquery css for command link

Tags: jquery, jsf, hover, slide, jquery-hover

the code is as follows 
What problem am I facing? I want jquery button slide to work for the command link in the jsf code. I have tried every alternative but not getting proper output.
Jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.button_bLeft').hover(
                function () {
                    var $this       = $(this);
                    var $slidelem   = $this.prev();
                    $slidelem.stop().animate({'width':'225px'},300);
                    $slidelem.find('span').stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    $this.addClass('button_c');
                },
                function () {
                    var $this       = $(this);
                    var $slidelem   = $this.prev();
                    $slidelem.stop().animate({'width':'70px'},200);
                    $slidelem.find('span').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                    $this.removeClass('button_c');
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Html Code-

```
        <a class="button_aLeft"><span>Sign In</span></a>
        <a class="button_bLeft">Sign</a>
```

JSF:

```
<td ><h:panelGrid columns="6" width="100%"  columnClasses="button_bLeft">
    <c:forEach items="#{collectionPlace}" var="places" class="button_aLeft">
    <c:if
        test="#{places.country eq allPlaces.country and places.regionName eq allState.regionName}">
                <h:commandLink action="#{placesManager.showDetail}"
                            value="#{places.cityName}" styleClass="b_one"                                                          
                                    render="panelgrp1,panel1:panelgrp3">
                                    <f:param name="cityid" value="#{places.placeid}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </td>
```

Comment: Is that all the html generated ? Can you post the complete HTML ? I mean, with the list of places, the table... The animation code looks good, The problem is only on JSF part as JQuery only affects HTML generated code

Answer (score 1):

Your JSF code does not make any sense. `<c:forEach class>`? `<h:commandLink render>`? Do you read [tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) [documentations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html)?

In any way, provided that you're actually asking the following:

> How do I use JSF `<h:commandLink>` in such way that it ultimately generates the following HTML output?
>
> ```
> <a class="button_aLeft"><span>Sign In</span></a>
> <a class="button_bLeft">Sign</a>
> ```

Then the answer is:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="button_aLeft"><span>Sign In</span></h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink styleClass="button_bLeft">Sign</h:commandLink>
```